# How to Get the Application Delegate in iMac

Tags: objective-c, xcode

In iPhone we use
(BadgerNewAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

What do we need to use when we are creating an iMac application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
YourAppDelegateClass *delegate = [[NSApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

Comment: mipadi that's even better. Can you turn that into an answer and I'll select that.

Answer (score 1):

try this

id appDelegate = [[NSApplication sharedApplication] delegate];